# Our on_initialize function takes approximately 5 seconds, this breaks the parachain eventually

Tags: parachain, kusama, block-production

We need to run an on-initialize function that runs for 5 to 6 seconds. The error we run into when we do this is "Block production took too long".

We have tried to increase the `AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO`, `NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO` and `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` accordingly to be able to fit it within the block length, however those don't seem to work.

Are there correct values for `AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO`, `NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO`, or `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` to help us achieve this? For context, we are trying to run this on Kusama chain.

Comment: do you have the source code public?

Comment: Why would you do that? Parachain blocks should not take that long or they can get their' chain stuck. Are you trying to do a migration or what?